# Visjs/React: Building a DataSet Dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vis.js, vis.js-network, vis.js-timeline

I am requesting data from a sever then trying to assign it to `items`. console.log is showing the correct data but I am getting an error: `Failed prop type: Invalid props 'items' of type 'object supplied to Timeline, expected array'. I thought`items.add` converted the dataset into an array?

```
var items = new vis.DataSet();
items.add(data.abs.map(a, index) => ({
  id: index + 1, 
  content: a.Ent, 
  start: a.time, 
  title: a.Trc, 
  end: null
})));
```

**DATA:**

```
"data": {
  "abs": [
    {
      "Ent": "Changed",
      "time": 1499348050000,
      "Trace": [
        {
          "filename": "C:/Users/Public/Desktop/word.doc"
        }
      ]  
    }
```

Comment: Can you also share the response data in order for anyone here to check that you're consuming it correctly?  You also don't reference element `a` ever in your map function, and if you want to access the original array `abs`, you need to pass that as the third parameter.  Did you really mean to do `content: a.Ent` etc?  `add` isn't an array function, so I'm pretty sure `items` isn't an array and that's why you get the propType warning.  Is `items` a set?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [vis.dataset docs](http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html), `add` doesn't convert the dataset, it just returns an array of the ids of the added items.  In your code example, the variable `items` is actually ***the*** dataset object itself.  When you call `items.add(...` that expression does return an array, but you don't capture it.  I assume you're passing items as a prop and it's still the dataset object, but you may be able to use the [`::map`](http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html#Data_Selection) function, it returns an array.

Comment: Can you provide and example of using `::map`?

Comment: Works just like javascript's array::map, [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wq495rny45)